# CSS Grid minmax(0,25%) won't set width to 0

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid, minmax

The need is to have the `.card-media` column width set to 0 when empty.

```css
.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 24%) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: 'card-media card-title' 'card-media card-content' 'card-action card-action';
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-media {
  grid-area: card-media;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-media"></div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="card-title">Title</div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <button class="btn">Some action</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case, although empty, the `.card-media` column remain at 24% width. Same result when using `minmax(auto, 24%)`.
Can I set that column to 0 using CSS Grid?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually looking for [fit-content()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content())

use it like this:

```css
grid-template-columns: fit-content(24%) 1fr;
```

And apply to `.card-media`

```css
min-width: 0;
```

to make it have no minimum width.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1eyu7t6a/1/)

Comment: Thank you. However this solution does not preserve the max width of 24% that .card-media has

Comment: updated answer. fit-content is the function you need instead of minmax.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet simply sets display: none if the element is empty:

```css
.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 24%) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-areas: 'card-media card-title' 'card-media card-content' 'card-action card-action';
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-media {
  grid-area: card-media;
  margin-right: 2%;
  float: left;
}

.card-media:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-media"></div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <div class="card-title">Title</div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <button class="btn">Some action</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works ! Thanks